# Compiling large projects with clang++

Tags: c++, compilation, project, clang++

I'm currently working on a c++ project with multiple .cpp and .h files. Although I can compile using

```
clang++ -c -o Polygon.cpp Vertex.o
```

for example, many of the classes are dependant on others, so I end up compiling multiple files including multiple objects which are included in multiple other compiles too. I also use a typedef

```
typedef std::pair<Vertex,Vertex> edge;
```

in several places, meaning it has to be included in several files, is there a neater/better way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: Use cmake or other build system for that

Answer (score 0):

The best way is too use `cmake`

Have a look to this tutorial:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake_tutorial.html

Also there is a small example:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html